# Lenovo IdeaPad 5 turns on but black screen

Tags: black-screen-of-death

This happened after a BIOS update.

Lenovo IdeaPad 5 turns on but black screen. Eventually I hear the fan but nothing on screen. The machine is running Windows 10.

I have done a battery drain, I have tried off and on pin reset.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the computer is OFF.

Turn ON.  Immediately press F1 (for BIOS) repeatedly and get BIOS to start.

Once in BIOS, reset BIOS to default, save, exit and restart (it should start itself).

This approach will normally start a Lenovo machine that will not start after a BIOS update, and I have used this approach.

If for any reason you cannot get into BIOS to reset it, then you need to have the machine serviced at a local computer shop.